# Scanlines on monitor

Tags: display, vga

I'm not sure if this is also a place to ask hardware related questions, but I'm having scanline problems with my monitor when my laptop is plugged in the power socket. What can I do to make that problem go away?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a toroid kicking around (motherboards often come with them), you can try wrapping a portion of the video cable through it to see if that makes any difference.  I take it that this is a CRT monitor?

Comment: It is an LCD screen. I use a vga cable

Comment: What do the lines look like?  How many are there?  Are they horizontal?  Do they move?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to make it go away is going to be to use a DVI cable instead, but that may not be a possible solution.

Alternatively, try swapping your VGA cable to a higher quality cable, and make sure that your outlets are properly grounded electrically.  There could also be a grounding problem inside the laptop or the monitor itself, but that's not something that will be user-servicable.